# How do I change the speed of the app drawer appearing?

Tags: gnome-shell, customization, effects, animations

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 today, and noticed that a lot of desktop environment has now changed from Ubuntu 17.04.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to change the the setting of those desktop effect for example, Change the speed of the app drawer to appear when you click it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Things look and feel different as Ubuntu 17.10 comes with GNOME shell instead of Unity like before.

To change the app-drawer animation speed you may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called ["Impatience" from here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/277/impatience/). It provides the option to speed up/down GNOME shell animations.

Once installed and activated, reload the page and you'll see a settings icon. Click on it and you'll get a pop-up window which lets you change the animation speed.

[image]