# Alt+Tab show-up speed is too slow - can I make it instant on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10, gnome-shell, application-switcher

Is there any way to change the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> speed to show up to instant in Ubuntu 17.10? I previously used 16.04 and I was somehow able to adjust the speed with `compiz` I believe, but since Ubuntu 17.10 uses GNOME 3, I can't find any option or way to reduce the 0.2 seconds or so that the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination actually takes to show up.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/971267/480481

Comment: thanks. What do I do if my version isn't on the list of downloads?

Comment: Try it anyway! Works fine for me with GNOME shell v3.26 even though it's not on the list of "supported" versions.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to change the Alt+Tab show up speed for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this you could install a GNOME Shell extension. You can find a short tutorial on how to do this here: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)
or [this external link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/install-gnome-extensions-ubuntu-17-10/).

Basically once you have installed the GNOME Shell integration add-on for your favorite browser and the [GNOME Shell integration for Chrome](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) on your system - go to [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/) and search for

> Alt-Tab Switcher Popup Delay Removal by xhfhope

or go directly to

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1317/alt-tab-switcher-popup-delay-removal/

and install the extension (you should only need to click on the switch and turn it "on"). Now the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> delay should be gone.

I don't even understand why [this delay](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/switcherPopup.js#L16) exists. 
Basically, what the extension does is the following (I'm not the author of this extension):

```
function init(){
    defaultValue = imports.ui.switcherPopup.POPUP_DELAY_TIMEOUT;
}

function enable(){
    imports.ui.switcherPopup.POPUP_DELAY_TIMEOUT = 0;
}

function disable(){
    imports.ui.switcherPopup.POPUP_DELAY_TIMEOUT = defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer although could you explain a bit more in detail what your code does and where it must be implemented?

Comment: Hey, @uitty400. This is not my code :) I just wanted to show what this extension does. It removes the delay which was done on purpose. As a user, you just need to install this extension.

Comment: Thanks Andrei! This solution worked. Was not easy to know follow your answer though. I edited it a bit to make it easier to follow for less experienced users (like me).

Comment: @uitty400 yep :)